# Add text to video at certain times

Tags: python, video-editing

I currently have a video (.wav file) and I want to add text that will scroll throughout the video. All the python Libraries I can find don't have a way to add text.

Basically say the video length was 10 min. Id love a way to do someLibrary.setText(xPos,YPos,Time)

which stays there till I give it a new one . so if I did that at 5 min, and another one at 6 min, it would stay on screen 1 min and be replaced by the next one.

Does such a thing exist or a workaround solution to doing this?

Comment: How about [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videotools.html?highlight=subtitle#module-moviepy.video.tools.subtitles)?

Comment: I believe this only works with srt files. If this is the only solution I might have to go that route, but ideally id like to do it by command line in script.

Comment: I see. [In this example page](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/examples/moving_letters.html), simple text 'Cool effect' is inserted.